# How plot every ten dataframes in a dictionary ? Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dictionary of 100 dataframes and I would like to plot juste every ten dataframe. I tried this but I have this error:

```
keys = dfs.keys()  #keys = dict_keys([1,2,...,100])

# iterate through the dataframe dictionary keys and use enumerate
for idx, key in range(0,len(keys),10):                                      <----------
    dfs[key]['Value'].plot(ax=ax_array[idx], title=f'DataFrame: {key}')
plt.tight_layout()

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

I know that the problem is in the definition of the for loop itself.
But I would like to plot :

```
dfs[1], dfs[10], dfs[20],...,dfs[100]
```

Comment: `idx, key in range(0,len(keys),10)` range outputs a single number. you're expecting it to unpack into two values

Comment: Is `keys` a `dict`?

Comment: Can you show where `keys` is defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
for idx, (key, df) in enumerate(dfs.items()):
    df['Value'].plot(ax=ax_array[idx], title=f"DataFrame: {key})
```

That automatically uses the keys and values of `dfs`, and with `enumerate`, you get the loop index as well. Just make sure to group things accordingly: the loop variable is actually a tuple of the index and a key-value tuple, that is, `(idx, (key, value))`, where you can leave off the outer parentheses, and I've replaced `value` with `df` for clarity.

---

You actually want to step through every x items, which isn't really a thing to use a dictionary for. So you would be better off just putting all your dataframes in a list. Then, the above would become:

```
for idx, df in enumerate(dfs[::10]):
    df['Value'].plot(ax=ax_array[idx], title=f"DataFrame: {idx+1})
```

which plots every 10th dataframe.

Notice the `"... {idx+1}"`, which I've added, since your question indicates you prefer 1-based numbering for the dataframe identifier (which makes sense, as it's output to humans), and `idx` is 0-based.

---

Now for your actual problem and answer:

```
keys = sorted(dfs)
for idx, key in enumerate(keys[::10]):
    dfs[key]['Value'].plot(ax=ax_array[idx], title=f"DataFrame: {key+1})
```

You see that here, `dfs[key]` needs to accessed separately, since we can't step through the items of a dict every nth item (as explained above).

Note that I've added `sorted()`. You may not want or need it. Newer versions of (C)Python preserve the insertion order, so without it, your dataframes will show up in the way they were added.

Also note that sorting on a dictionary directly, means sorting on its keys (this is the case for anything that iterates over a dictionary: it implicitly iterates over its keys).

Comment: but how do you deal with the plot every ten dataframes ?  (plot dfs[1], dfs[10], dfs[20],...)

Comment: Ah, right, that escaped me. Probably because with a dictionary, you don't really deal with "every x items", since the items aren't numbered (or ordered. Technically, they are, but not from a theoretical, or even usage, point of view).

Comment: @ThonyNadhir I've extended my answer to include the step factor, with an addition on why a dict with (ordered) integers is not really the best starting point (it has its uses, but not here).